# Browser supports sencha touch

Tags: browser, sencha-touch

I wanted to know that which browser in mobile is supporting sencha-touch applications.
I am currently testing my app in chrome on desktop and it is working well.But when I am going to tried opera mini , it was not working. 
Can anybody let me know that which browsers are compatible(in both desktop and mobile)for sencha-touch applications?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665442/sencha-touch-and-internet-explorer-10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the browsers which are using webkit. This includes Google Chrome and Safari on the desktop.

In the [official site](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/), they are saying the following:

> It's currently compatible with Apple
>   iOS, Android, and BlackBerry 6
>   devices. Together these devices
>   represent over 95% of current US
>   mobile traffic.