# Sencha Touch and Internet Explorer 10

Tags: extjs, internet-explorer-10

Sencha Touch is brilliant but IE cannot open websites which is developed using Sencha Touch.
I am not interested in using IE, but my opinion is not important since many others may use it.

Since Microsoft announces HTML-5 Support and I have worked with the great tools to make native apps even using HTML-5 and Java so it is obvious that IE 10 must support HTML5. But it seems sencha touch websites cannot be explored by IE 10 too, since I cannot explore Kitchen Sink (on sencha.com) using IE 10 however I can easily do this using Chrome.

Further to this problem, I want to make an web-site for a small company, is it right to use Sencha Touch to develop it or jQuery is a better choice? (I yearn for you say Sencha Touch :) since I am completely unfamiliar with jQuery)

I appreciate the time you are spending.
Sincerely yours,
PEYMAN MORTAZAVI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call me old-fashioned, but when I see the Kitchen Sink demo failing in IE10, I blame the developers behind the demo, and not those behind the browser. IE10 is an oustanding browser that is worthy of our attention, and not merely for the fact that it will be used by millions upon millions immediately following its official release, but also because it's a great browser from a technical perspective.

If you're going to build a solution for your clients, you should avoid libraries that wish to distance themselves from supporting half of the market, meaning they don't actively develop with IE in mind. The excuses for *not* supporting IE simply aren't there today as your code won't require that much variance to work properly in the latest version of Microsoft's browser.

Use jQuery, jQuery Mobile, or jQuery UI. You can get some great UI from and with all of them, and you'll find excellent support in all major browsers.

Comment: Right, SenchaTouch is really great, but when we are talking about making a Web site that clients will check. removing support from a popular browser like Internet Explorer is some kind of sueside ;)

Comment: IE10 is another IE crappy browser. Better just use Google Chrome Frame as AutomaticLuke suggested; the user will still "use" IE but its performance will be greatly improved and you won't have to spend double to maintain the website for IE

Comment: Mihai, IE10 is an incredibly solid browser and doesn't require hardly any special attention when developing with standards in mind. I suspect you have not used it all that often, but I can say that after 9 months of daily use, it is a very reliable product.

Comment: @johnathan well it has the last place in the HTML5 support so I can tell you that it sucks now and it will suck even more in the next year when vital HTML5 features will be supported in all the other browsers  but you won't be able to take advantage of them because of IE. Just like IE was not too bad when it reached IE6 version but now definitely is not good at all and is still there because microsoft doesn't update it. You can say the same about IE9, IE8, IE7, IE6. Why to invest in a failed product ?

Comment: @mihai I'm not sure what you're talking about; IE10 supports a great deal of "HTML5" features. So much so that it provides the best experience when it comes to high-quality games like [Contre Jour](http://www.contrejour.ie), even better than Chrome or Firefox. I'm also not sure what you mean by Microsoft "doesn't update it." You do realize that IE8+ is an entirely new browser, right? IE9 and IE10 introduced great support for edge-technologies. And how exactly is IE a failed product when it has 50+% use, and strong-standards support today?

Comment: @JonathanSampson the great deal of html5 features that IE10 supports are not so great. It holds the last place in html5 support so you can say that it supports some html5 but actually has the worst support.  See here a comparison here http://caniuse.com/#compare=ie+10,chrome+24 . The "unknown" are actually not supported. You make me laugh about that game. It's a demo specially made to work on IE10 as a marketing material to promote IE10. About the "entirely new browser" microsoft is the only browser vendor that doesn't update it automatically . Do you see any chrome 2 version ?

Comment: @JonathanSampson IE9 same as IE8 decided to support "CORS" through a proprietary method  "XDomainRequest" saying that is more secure the standard XHR based on CORS specs. Finally in IE10 they realized how stupid they were and added CORS support. There are uncountable examples such this we should not invest in a such flawed product. IE10 of course will run nice on a few demos that microsoft sponsors but within 3 months it will remain outdated while the other vendors will get better and better. So if now IE holds the last place think what place it will hold within 2 -3 months after launch.

Comment: @JonathanSampson is popular because it's the default browser not because is better. However it has about 40% share not 50+ . See latest 3 months chart http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser-US-monthly-201207-201209-bar . I hope  and think that will change soon as EU is requiring microsoft to provide a screen so the user can choose what browser to use instead to get by default IE so it will loose even more marketshare.

Comment: Sencha Touch is a mobile framework.  IE does not have 50% (or 40%) of browser share on mobile, it's more like 5%.  Sencha Touch is designed to work with Webkit browsers, of which IE is not one, so there is no reason to expect it will work.

Comment: @Sharon Valid point, however IE is becoming increasingly more prevalent in the Mobile market and as such any site built on a technology that intentionally worked for one particular vendor will immediately experience problems as IE's mobile market share grows. Not only IE, but also mobile Firefox and others as well.

Comment: @JonathanSampson Whether or not IE's mobile market share will grow or not is unknown, but I know that the Sencha Touch team has been working with Microsoft to build support for Windows Phone devices.  We will likely see support for non-webkit browsers in the near future.

Answer (score 3):

I am porting my Sencha Touch 2.0 app  to 2.2.1 in order to support IE10.
So I have first-hand knowledge in the effort.

1. all Sencha websites / apps build previous to 2.2.0 and by developers targeting webkit browsers will never work on ie10 reliably because a bunch of stuff had to be done to the core of Sencha Touch in order for ie10 to work.  Everyone has to go back and do what I'm doing... line by line of CSS and a few JS changes as well (esp if you do canvas stuff)
2. Running an old "kitchen sink" which was not properly architected for 2.2.1 **and** tested on IE10 is not going to work either. I do not know how much time Sencha folks spent testing kitchen sink on IE10 ...but one would assume...
3. I think what has thrown Sencha for a loop is developers don't have time or money to build business apps twice - once on ExtJS for laptop/desktop and 2nd time on Sencha Touch 2 for tablet touch/gesture support.  This is the strange land of SDK's because the tablet real-estate so closely resembles that of a small laptop -- ergo as long as your UX people a really good, they can architect an experience that crosses over from tablet to laptop pretty good by building one code base in Sencha Touch.

But oooops - Sencha figured we'd all be building to small phones - a market dominated by webkit browsers.  If that were the case, then this argument of IE market share would not hold - we all know Windows Phone numbers. It's hard to fudge/spin that. What's causing the rub is the tablet-laptop screen size being so similar.

IMHO...

Answer (score 2):

IE10 in the Windows 8 preview is the same version that is slated for the tablets and mobile devices they have been producing.  Saying it is for desktop support is not a very useful statement.  The problem is this is what Microsoft is about to spend a very large amount of money marketing and pushing to businesses.  This is not a case of a tablet/phone library not supporting a desktop, but of a tablet/phone library not supporting a target platform that is about to have billions of dollars of marketing spent to deploy it.

Answer (score 2):

Any mention of Internet explorer seems to evoke deep emotion in everyone! However IE is a fact of life.

I would suggest that you use Google Chrome Frame. The first time IE visitors arrive at your site you can alert the user to install Google Chrome Frame and redirect them. It's a bit messy for the first visit but after that it should be seamless.

As I understand it Google Chrome Frame no longer requires admin rights to install.

Obviously people should just install Chrome in the first place but nobody's perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Sencha Touch 2 is not designed to work on IE10. If desktop support is important for you, then you should use Ext JS 4.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome and Safari use [WebKit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) which Sencha Touch requires in order to function.

Internet Explorer might be able to display Sencha Touch apps in the future:

http://www.appleinsider.com/articles/08/11/06/microsofts_ballmer_considers_using_webkit_within_ie.html

http://www.favbrowser.com/opera-firefox-and-internet-explorer-to-implement-webkit-prefixes/

But who knows?

Answer (score 0):

I had spent a month getting a project to work with Sencha Touch, but had to choose a more accessable framework. The goals of the project were to work across as many browsers (desktop and mobile) as possible. The webkit preference for Sencha, while admirable in how it is achieved, made it unusable for my needs.

I am glad they changed their licensing since I tried it. That was the second stumbling point for our project.